# The type or namespace name 'RoleExists' does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider, asp.net-roles

I'm trying to add roles programatically using Sql Membership Provider, like show below:

```
string newRoleName = RoleName.Text.Trim();

        if (!Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName))
        {
             // Create the role 
            Roles.CreateRole(newRoleName); 
            RoleName.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

I added this namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.ApplicationServices;
```

I'm getting the following error:

The type or namespace name 'RoleExists' does not exist in the namespace  (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How can I resolved that?

Comment: Are you able to access and use other aspects of the membership provider like MembershipUser CreateUser etc. Or do these error out as well?

Comment: I can CreateUser and Login... but when I tried to use the Role.(some method) I'm got the error mention above. Any idea why is passing that?

Comment: And have you got the rolemanager enabled in the web.config?

Comment: Yes is enable... I achieved do resolved this problem.... But I had that used the absolute route for access to the Roles's Methods.... ystem.Web.Security.Roles.(Role Method)... Why you beleive that is not added to "using" System.Web.Security?